# How do I uncompress a quite big tar file which is 200GB larger much than memory?

Tags: compression

As the Title says the file is too big. In fact, I want to uncompress wikipedia-en-html.tar.

Comment: Are you wanting to extract the contents of a compressed TAR files without initially unzipping the TAR file?  Is it gzip'd or bzip'd ?

Comment: I have already unzipped it from wikipedia-en-html.tar.7z to wikipedia-en-html.tar, it becomes 218BG from 15GB

Comment: I guess you mean extract from it then rather than uncompress?  Are you using windows or Linux?

Comment: Yes, I have both. If you can tell me a way to do it in either platform, I'll be so appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an archive that is compressed, you don't need to uncompress it on disk before extracting the files.  Tar files were originally (IIRC :) ) created for tape based storage, so their contents can be streamed, therefore you can simply pipe the output of the decompression algorithm into tar via stdout/stdin

For 7zip you could use:

```
7z x -so wikipedia-en-html.tar.7z | tar xv
```

This will write the contents of the file into the current directory and echo the filenames as it's going.  If you don't want to see the files as it's going simply remove the 'v' from tar.

The switches to 7zip tell it to e'x'tract and -so tells it to use StOut instead of writing to disk.

For gzip/bzip you can just use tar as it has plugins already built in for these (I couldn't see one for 7zip)

```
tar zxvf your.tar.gz
```

will extract a gzipped file

```
tar jxvf your.tar.bz2
```

will extract a bzip2'd tar file

Those are the most common